How can I make the arrow move when hovering over the entire button using Next.js and Framer Motion?
Below is the code that displays a button containing a label and a circle. And in that circle an arrow. The arrow now moves infinitely (in a movement from left to right and back), but the arrow should only move when hovering over the entire button. The circle and label should not move. Does anyone have an idea how I can achieve this? Tried many ways but haven't found a good solution yet.
View an example of the button here:

"use client";

import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import Link from "next/link";

type Props = {
  label: string;
  url: string;
};

export default function Button({ label, url }: Props) {
  return (
    <>
      <Link href={`/${url}`}>
        <motion.button
          style={{
            width: "350px",
            height: "70px",
            backgroundColor: "none",
            display: "flex",
            alignItems: "center",
            padding: "0 20px",
            marginTop: "40px",
            cursor: "pointer",
            outline: "none",
          }}
        >
          <div
            style={{
              width: "70px",
              height: "70px",
              borderRadius: "50%",
              border: "2px solid rgb(234 88 12)",
              display: "flex",
              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "center",
              marginLeft: "-20px",
              overflow: "hidden",
              position: "relative",
            }}
          >
            <motion.svg
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              style={{
                width: "30px",
                height: "30px",
                position: "absolute",
              }}
              animate={{
                x: [-60, 50],
              }}
              transition={{
                repeat: Infinity,
                duration: 1,
                repeatType: "reverse",
              }}
            >
              <motion.path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
              <motion.path
                d="m14.523 18.787s4.501-4.505 6.255-6.26c.146-.146.219-.338.219-.53s-.073-.383-.219-.53c-1.753-1.754-6.255-6.258-6.255-6.258-.144-.145-.334-.217-.524-.217-.193 0-.385.074-.532.221-.293.292-.295.766-.004 1.056l4.978 4.978h-14.692c-.414 0-.75.336-.75.75s.336.75.75.75h14.692l-4.979 4.979c-.289.289-.286.762.006 1.054.148.148.341.222.533.222.19 0 .378-.072.522-.215z"
                fill="white"
              />
            </motion.svg>
          </div>
          <span
            style={{ marginLeft: "20px", color: "white", fontSize: "24px" }}
          >
            {label}
          </span>
        </motion.button>
      </Link>
    </>
  );
}


You can do this without framer motion, save yourself some kb. Add a hover affect on the parent div that only affects the child, you will need to use css or scss

Thanx Devon for your response! It is indeed easier to fix with CSS. I'm going to follow your advice.
